# How to inject a piece of JS code into an 3rd party web page?

Tags: javascript, web

I am trying to do some POC of client side utilities for a 3rd party web page. I want to inject a piece of my experimental JS into that page. But I don't have access to the target page. Is there any way to do it?

### ADD 1

Ideally, I want to do it with IE 10.
And I want to place the JS file locally on my disk, and have it loaded automatically.

### ADD 2

Just found one related thread: [Injecting JavaScript into head element of website using Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933934/injecting-javascript-into-head-element-of-website-using-fiddler)

Comment: Open the console and knock yourself out.

Comment: You can't just inject a piece of code to someone's web if they didn't ask for it.

Comment: @hex494D49 I do this only for local test purpose. And only myself will be affected.

Comment: WOW. You should also mention that this is nasa website, and the new 2020 cosmic program top secret web page panel. This is not that easy... If it was, the internet would be a piece of rubbish till today :).

Comment: If this is possible - there goes on-line banking for a start

Comment: Well, there's always some tricks we don't know.

Comment: you can use chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I didn't describe my question clear enough so many people think this cannot be done.

Inspired by this thread: [Injecting JavaScript into head element of website using Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933934/injecting-javascript-into-head-element-of-website-using-fiddler), it turns out I can use FiddlerScript to achieve this.

Steps are:

1. Set the `oSession.bBufferResponse = true;` in `OnBeforeRequest()`
   method so Fiddler proxy has a chance to buffer and modify the
   response.
2. Then modify the response as I want in `OnBeforeResponse()` method, where I can inject my JS into the response DOM.

For details: check the book < *Debugging with Fiddler* > by Eric Lawrence, chapter '*FiddlerScript*'

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new html document with the source, an add all the javascript you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to imagine what will happen if this would be possible.

And I think this is the answer to your question. This is mych more complicated / server / hardware / software / psychology / multi / complicated problem. Of course, sometimes there are a few possibilities to do it, but they are non universal / security holes cases.

Best regards!

BTW: But I don't have access to the target page. I assumed that you do not have access to the server too. As one implies another. If I'm mistaken, please update your question with more data.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but you can use Charles Proxy to do this and using the Rewrite feature you can place some code in there. I'm doing this for testing Google tag manager on some sites that don't belong to me :)